# Not able to set the string array in the list

Tags: android, arrays

I have a string array in arrays.xml. It is -

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="messages">
        <item>@string/hello</item>
        <item>@string/bye</item>
        <item>@string/hi</item>
        <item>@string/how_are_you</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

I read this in my MainActivity as -

```
String[] favouriteMessage;
public ArrayList<MyClass> arraylst;

favouriteMessage = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.messages);
final MyClass myclass = new MyClass(favouriteMessage);
arraylst.add(myclass);

//Send the arraylist to fragment
myFragment.setFavourites(arraylst);
```

In my MyClass,

```
public class MyClass {

    public String[] favourites;

    public MyClass(final String[] favouriteMessages){
        favourites = favouriteMessages;
    }
}
```

In myFragment,

```
public void setFavourites(ArrayList<MyClass> favourites) {
        this.favourites = favourites;
        favoritesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.favorites_adapter,favourites);

        lstView.setAdapter(favoritesAdapter);
    }
```

The problem is the list view is being showed as an object in a single item and not as a string. I definitely want my String array to be converted to object and do it.

Comment: how you can assign arraylist of object to string array ? check your code hope IDE will give you compile error.

Comment: You have a Custom Class (MyClass), that holds a String Array, and you add this custom Class to an ArrayList - so you have an ArrayList, with 1 object, that contains a String Array within said Object. You wonder why it isn't working? Just provide the Adapter with your String Array, or get the String Array using Arrays.asList from MyClass .. or one of 5 other ways of doing this ..

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here

```
arraylst.add(myclass);
```

If you want to conver xml array to list, you need to use this sample code:

```
<resources>
<string-array name="messages">
    <item>@string/hello</item>
    <item>@string/bye</item>
    <item>@string/hi</item>
    <item>@string/how_are_you</item>
</string-array>
```

```
String[] array = Resources().getStringArray(R.array.messages);
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

And then you can pass this list to list adapter.